# Is there a way to implement MS Word into my iOS application other than the url scheme method?

Tags: ios, swift, open-source

My app lets users to download *.doc files, currently I use url scheme method to open the file in the MS's app itself. Is there any provision to display and edit *.doc files directly within my app so that users do not have to have MS Word app installed on their iOS device? Is there any alternative ways to open and edit *.doc apps within my iOS app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no native component for viewing .doc files. There might be third party libraries you could integrate into your app that provide that functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Could you please name some of those libraries?

Comment: I have no idea. I'd have to search, just like you will. Try searches like "iOS MS Word framework" (and variants with library or API instead of "framework" and ".doc" instead of "MS Word")